# Can we set Redirect URI dynamically or set Redirect URI at runtime if it is not added already in the Stripe Connect Account?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a site with dynamic URLs, Now I want to set the Redirect URL in stripe standard account at runtime. I mean, For now, I am compelled to go to my account settings to redirect URL, is there any way we can add new redirect URLs using some API?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use the `state` property when you create an authorize link. This will be passed through the OAuth process.

`https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_123&scope=read_write&state=special-value`

When the user is redirected back to your site, you can grab the `state` value from the query string (`special-value` in my example) and then use that to help determine where to redirect the user to a final destination page after you [fetch the user's credentials](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#token-request).